# Randomised Image is displayed more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting, random

***Functionality:***

Brand image is randomised and is displayed within the container list. Each of the randomised brand image needs to be only displayed once.

***What has been done:***

Firstly, I have created an array of image files as `var ImageArray=["","","",....]`. Secondly, I have created a randomised method as var `random_BrandIndex =  Math.floor(Math.random() * BrandNameArray.length);` and lastly, I created a for loop that will allow the image to populate the table created within the html body.

I have attached the code for your perusal:

```js
//Brand Array
var BrandNameArray = ["lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Ads.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/AEO.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/AO.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Beauty.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Be.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/DS.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Cch.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Coton.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Dwel.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/esBr.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Et.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/E.png"];

$(function() {
  //Auto populate into brand container once randomised for each Brand image
  for (i = 0; i < $('#list').find('img').length; i++) {
    //To Set random Brand
    var random_BrandIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * BrandNameArray.length);
    //Assign Variable to generate random Brands
    var Brand = BrandNameArray[random_BrandIndex];
    $('#Brand_' + (i + 1)).attr('src', Brand);
    $('#Brand_' + (i + 1)).show();
    console.log(Brand);
  }
});
```

```css
.Container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  width: 1250px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.innerScroll {
  position: relative;
  width: 1250px;
  height: 600px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #8d8989 !important;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div id="list" class="innerScroll">
    <!--1st Row-->
    <img id="Brand_1" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:0px; border:0px; outline:0px" onclick="selectBrand('1');">
    <img id="Brand_2" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('2');">
    <img id="Brand_3" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:650px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('3');">
    <img id="Brand_4" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:965px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('4');">

    <!--2nd Row-->
    <img id="Brand_5" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:140px; left:0px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('5');">
    <img id="Brand_6" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:140px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('6');">
    <img id="Brand_7" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:140px; left:650px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('7');">
    <img id="Brand_8" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:140px; left:965px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('8');">

    <!--3rd Row-->
    <img id="Brand_9" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:0px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('9');">
    <img id="Brand_10" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('10');">
    <img id="Brand_11" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:650px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('11');">
    <img id="Brand_12" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:965px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('12');">

    <!--4th Row-->
    <img id="Brand_09" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:0px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('9');">
    <img id="Brand_10" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('10');">
    <img id="Brand_11" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:650px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('11');">
    <img id="Brand_12" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:965px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('12');">.....(more rows of images)...
  </div>
</div>
```

***Issue:***

At this point in time, the randomised images are displaying. However, some of the images displayed are displayed more than once.

Therefore, How is it possible for the randomised image to be only displayed once within the `<div id ="list">`?

please help. your help is much much appreciated.

Comment: Side note, make sure your IDs are unique

Comment: Use a proper array shuffling algorithm, such as Fisher-Yates algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting the element from the array, remove the item so that you don't get it again

```
var Brand = BrandNameArray[random_BrandIndex]; //existing line
BrandNameArray.splice(random_BrandIndex,1); //new line
```

Also, this array enclosed inside an anonymous method so you can be sure that this array is not used outside.

I am referring to this anonymous method (i have made the changes as well)

```
$(function() {
  var BrandNameArrayBackup = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(BrandNameArray)); //taking backup
  //Auto populate into brand container once randomised for each Brand image
  for (i = 0; i < $('#list').find('img').length; i++) {
    //To Set random Brand
    var random_BrandIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * BrandNameArray.length);
    //Assign Variable to generate random Brands
    var Brand = BrandNameArray[random_BrandIndex];
    BrandNameArray.splice(random_BrandIndex,1); //new line 
    $('#Brand_' + (i + 1)).attr('src', Brand);
    $('#Brand_' + (i + 1)).show();
    console.log(Brand);
  }
  BrandNameArray = BrandNameArrayBackup;//re-assigning values back to array
});
```

Comment: I don't really get your meaning. What do you mean by remove the item? and when you mean anonymous method, are you referring to a separate method?

Comment: @Luke refer to the changes in post

Comment: could you kindly explain why is there a need for a JSON.parse?

Comment: @luke to take the backup of the Array

Comment: But this will lead to a chain effect for other button actions, for e.g if I have a second button call "Re-Randomise" that does the exact same randomising method, and in the method, is the exact function call. It will not call the method when click.

Comment: @luke why would this array have chain effect on other button actions since it is enclosed inside a method and is not accessible outside? Have you tried these changes?

Comment: Yes,i have.  alright, so, if I have a secondary button that does perform the same randomising function of the images to be only displayed once. It wouldnt be correct if I were to use the same JSON method in that secondary button method. am I right?

Comment: @Luke kindly read the answer again. When you take a backup of the exisiting array and do operations on the backup array, how would it matter if the same operation is done once or twice? So I ask again - Have you tried this?

Comment: Yeaps, I have tried. And Secondly, I have use the same method on a secondary different button, but it wasnt calling the operations.

Comment: @Luke try the edited version once. updated the second last line.

Comment: what is it that you have done??what is the difference between the newly edited one and the previous one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107593/discussion-between-luke-and-gurvinder372).

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Brand Array
var BrandNameArray = ["lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Ads.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/AEO.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/AO.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Beauty.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Be.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/DS.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Cch.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Coton.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Dwel.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/esBr.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Et.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/E.png"];

$(function() {
  //Auto populate into brand container once randomised for each Brand image
  for (i = 0; i < $('#list').find('img').length; i++) {
    //To Set random Brand
    var random_BrandIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * BrandNameArray.length);
    //Assign Variable to generate random Brands
    var Brand = BrandNameArray[random_BrandIndex];
    $('#Brand_' + (i + 1)).attr('src', Brand);
    $('#Brand_' + (i + 1)).show();
    console.log(Brand);
  }
});
```

```css
.Container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  width: 1250px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.innerScroll {
  position: relative;
  width: 1250px;
  height: 600px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #8d8989 !important;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div id="list" class="innerScroll">
    <!--1st Row-->
    <img id="Brand_1" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:0px; border:0px; outline:0px" onclick="selectBrand('1');">
    <img id="Brand_2" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('2');">
    <img id="Brand_3" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:650px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('3');">
    <img id="Brand_4" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:965px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('4');">

    <!--2nd Row-->
    <img id="Brand_5" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:140px; left:0px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('5');">
    <img id="Brand_6" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:140px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('6');">
    <img id="Brand_7" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:140px; left:650px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('7');">
    <img id="Brand_8" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:140px; left:965px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('8');">

    <!--3rd Row-->
    <img id="Brand_9" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:0px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('9');">
    <img id="Brand_10" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('10');">
    <img id="Brand_11" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:650px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('11');">
    <img id="Brand_12" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:965px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('12');">

    <!--4th Row-->
    <img id="Brand_09" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:0px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('9');">
    <img id="Brand_10" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('10');">
    <img id="Brand_11" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:650px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('11');">
    <img id="Brand_12" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:965px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('12');">.....(more rows of images)...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Brand Array
var BrandNameArray = ["lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Ads.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/AEO.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/AO.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Beauty.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Be.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/DS.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Cch.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Coton.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Dwel.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/esBr.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Et.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/E.png"];

$(function() {
  //Auto populate into brand container once randomised for each Brand image
  for (i = 0; i < $('#list').find('img').length; i++) {
    //To Set random Brand
    var random_BrandIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * BrandNameArray.length);
    //Assign Variable to generate random Brands
    var Brand = BrandNameArray[random_BrandIndex];
    $('#Brand_' + (i + 1)).attr('src', Brand);
    $('#Brand_' + (i + 1)).show();
    console.log(Brand);
  }
});
```

```css
.Container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  width: 1250px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.innerScroll {
  position: relative;
  width: 1250px;
  height: 600px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #8d8989 !important;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div id="list" class="innerScroll">
    <!--1st Row-->
    <img id="Brand_1" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:0px; border:0px; outline:0px" onclick="selectBrand('1');">
    <img id="Brand_2" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('2');">
    <img id="Brand_3" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:650px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('3');">
    <img id="Brand_4" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:965px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('4');">

    <!--2nd Row-->
    <img id="Brand_5" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:140px; left:0px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('5');">
    <img id="Brand_6" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:140px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('6');">
    <img id="Brand_7" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:140px; left:650px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('7');">
    <img id="Brand_8" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:140px; left:965px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('8');">

    <!--3rd Row-->
    <img id="Brand_9" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:0px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('9');">
    <img id="Brand_10" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('10');">
    <img id="Brand_11" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:650px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('11');">
    <img id="Brand_12" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:965px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('12');">

    <!--4th Row-->
    <img id="Brand_09" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:0px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('9');">
    <img id="Brand_10" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('10');">
    <img id="Brand_11" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:650px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('11');">
    <img id="Brand_12" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:965px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('12');">.....(more rows of images)...
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
//Brand Array
var BrandNameArray = ["lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Ads.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/AEO.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/AO.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Beauty.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Be.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/DS.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Cch.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Coton.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Dwel.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/esBr.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/Et.png", "lib/img/PAGE03/Brands/E.png"];

$(function() {
  //Auto populate into brand container once randomised for each Brand image
  for (i = 0; i < $('#list').find('img').length; i++) {
    //To Set random Brand
    var random_BrandIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * BrandNameArray.length);
    //Assign Variable to generate random Brands
    var Brand = BrandNameArray[random_BrandIndex];
    $('#Brand_' + (i + 1)).attr('src', Brand);
    $('#Brand_' + (i + 1)).show();
    console.log(Brand);
  }
});
```

```css
.Container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  width: 1250px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.innerScroll {
  position: relative;
  width: 1250px;
  height: 600px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #8d8989 !important;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div id="list" class="innerScroll">
    <!--1st Row-->
    <img id="Brand_1" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:0px; border:0px; outline:0px" onclick="selectBrand('1');">
    <img id="Brand_2" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('2');">
    <img id="Brand_3" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:650px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('3');">
    <img id="Brand_4" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:0px; left:965px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('4');">

    <!--2nd Row-->
    <img id="Brand_5" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:140px; left:0px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('5');">
    <img id="Brand_6" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:140px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('6');">
    <img id="Brand_7" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:140px; left:650px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('7');">
    <img id="Brand_8" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:140px; left:965px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('8');">

    <!--3rd Row-->
    <img id="Brand_9" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:0px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('9');">
    <img id="Brand_10" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('10');">
    <img id="Brand_11" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:650px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('11');">
    <img id="Brand_12" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:965px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('12');">

    <!--4th Row-->
    <img id="Brand_09" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:0px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('9');">
    <img id="Brand_10" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('10');">
    <img id="Brand_11" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:650px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('11');">
    <img id="Brand_12" style="width:284px; height:140px; top:280px; left:965px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('12');">.....(more rows of images)...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you expand on this answer? Code only answers are difficult for others to follow.